# Something concrete about Bluetooth and profiles

Tags: c++, c, bluetooth

Alright so seeing as finding any concrete information about Bluetooth development is like pulling teeth out of a young lion, I really need some help with understanding the CONCRETE implementation of a bluetooth device. More specifically I can set up an RFCOMM connection between two device, but:

1. What now? I can send strings back and forth hurray, but what if I want to use one of the many illusive and poorly-described profiles? There is literally not a single shred of code on the internet that shows a concrete implementation of this.
2. This assumes question 1 can be answered, but: What if I want to use multiple profiles on one device? Do I need multiple sockets or is one fine? Are profiles just specific formats that get translated into a string and then sent? Is it possible to "weave" two different profile messages together and then send them through the same connection? Again I can find a specification of how this should be done on an abstract level, but there's nothing concrete at all anywhere to be found.

I've been developing this in C++ mostly by reading and copying C code from [here](http://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/index.html) but it doesn't do much beyond establishing a basic connection and then writing "Hello" through it. I'm at my wits end and honestly confused why there's so little documentation out there. Do they just want Bluetooth development to die? Somebody save me from this situation!

Comment: SO doesn't work that way. Please take some time to read the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help) page.

Comment: You mean the part under "What topics can I ask about here?" that clearly states: "a specific programming problem"?